# Actions must be plain object. Use custom middleware for async actions React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist'
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import allReducers from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(
  allReducers,
  {},
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    autoRehydrate()
  )
);
persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage });
export default store;
```

I'm using expo react native. I get the above-mentioned error on this code

Following is the code for **actions**

```
import * as types from './types';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';


export const getLocalToken = async () => {
    const localToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@auth:localToken');
    const mobileNumber = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@auth:mobileNumber');
    console.log("GLT", mobileNumber);
    if (localToken != null) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({
                type: types.GET_LOCALTOKEN_SUCCESS,
                payload: { localToken: this.localToken, mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber }
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({
                type: types.GET_LOCALTOKEN_FAIL
            })
        }
    }

}


export const verifyOTP = (mobileNumber, OTPNumber) => {
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    this.OTPNumber = OTPNumber
    console.log("HTTP request => ", mobileNumber);
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log("Requesting HTTP");
        dispatch({
            type: types.OTP_ENTERED_SUBMIT
        });

        fetch('http://192.168.100.199/api/VerifyOTP', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                mobileNumber: this.mobileNumber,
                OTPNumber: this.OTPNumber
            })
        })
            .then((response) => response.json()).then(
            (responseJson) => {
                console.log('HTTP response,', responseJson);
                return verifyOTPResponse(dispatch, responseJson);
            }).catch(
            (error) => { console.error(error); }
            );
    }
}
```

I get this error at dispatch. I'm new to react redux. It was working well until I add ***persistStore*** to the redux store.I get this error at dispatch. I'm new to react redux. It was working well until I add ***persistStore*** to the redux store.

Comment: Are you making async calls to api in your actions?

Comment: yes. I'm making API calls in actions

Comment: can you paste code for actions?

Comment: @mradziwon Added code in the question. Kindly check.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have `return (dispatch) => {}` within if & else statements? Why not `return (dispatch) => { if { dispatch({}) } else { dispatch({}) } }`. This might be the source of your problem.

Comment: Let me check it and update you soon!

Answer (score 0):

This is just to assist anyone else facing similar problem. I may not fix the problem the OP has but the following should help point you in the right direction ( I know it did for me ).

The problem arises due to the one line, `const store`.
I had problems hitting `https://swapi.co/api/people/21` from my action but if I hit it in my `componentWillMount` it works just fine.
Using `thunk` saved me. So, my final `store` looks like the following.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
const store = createStore(allReducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

For anyone looking for a more well rounded answer, follow [this answer to an issue raised on GitHub.](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/58#issuecomment-413330349)